# Como fazer troca de sprite sheet na unity sem precisar fazer mais animações?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Olá,

estou fazendo um jogo onde será possível fazer troca de personagem na unity.
O jogo será em 2d, para android e estou enfrentando problemas para fazer a troca de personagens.

Eu fiz um sistema funcional de troca, porem ele é muito extenso e será extremamente cansativo fazer para todos os personagens.
Fiz um aquivo para guardar um int de seleção de personagem. Até ai tudo bem, mas pra cada personagem tenho que fazer todas suas animações de novo. Com um animatorpra cada um.

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu usar o mesmo animator e animações pra todos os personagens, apenas trocando o sprite sheet que ele vai ultilizar?

desde de já muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho certeza, porém seria mais facil criar um tipo de asset para cada animação, assim:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Custom Assets/Animation 2D")]
public class Animation2D : ScriptableObject
{
   public Sprite[] Frames;
   public float FrameSpeed = 0.1f;
   public Sprite this[int index]{get{return Frames[index];}}
}
```

E depois uma classe que serviria para executar essa animação internamente, assim:

```
[Serializable]
public class Animation2DInstance
{
 public SpriteRender Render;
 public Animation2D Animation;
 public int CurrentFrame;
 public void RunFrame()
 {
   Render.sprite = Animation[CurrentFrame];
   CurrentFrame++;
 }
}
```

Depois na clase que executa essas animações, faça os seguintes metodos:

```
public void Play(Animation2D anim){StartCoroutine(execute_anim(anim));}
public IEnumerator execute_anim(Animation2D anim)
{
 Animation2DInstance instance = new Animation2DInstance(anim);
 float time = anim.FrameSpeed;
 int l = anim.Frames.Lenght;
 while(instance.CurrentFrame < l)
 {
   instance.RunFrame();
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é criar um Script como o seguinte:

```
public int spriteAtual;
public Sprite[] sprites;
private SpriteRenderer img;

void Start
{
    img = gameObject.getComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}
void Update
{
    img.Sprite = sprites[spriteAtual];
}
```

E na animação você só muda o valor do int spriteAtual, assim o código vai atualizar a Sprite de acordo com o valor do int, depois é só mudar as sprites da matriz "sprites" no inspector e reutilizar o código e a animação sem precisar de mais nada. Caso ainda queria mudar as sprites por código pode ainda criar várias matrizes e usar a função Switch como abaixo

```
public int animacaoX;
public int spriteAtual;
public Sprite[] spritesDaAnimacaoX;
public Sprite[] spritesDaAnimacaoX2;
public Sprite[] spritesDaAnimacaoX3;
private SpriteRenderer img;

void Start
{
    img = gameObject.getComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}

void Update
{
    img.Sprite = animacaoAtual(animacaoX)[spriteAtual];
}

Sprite[] AnimacaoAtual()
{
    Switch qualAnimacao
        case 1:
            return spritesDaAnimacaoX[];
            break;

        case 2:
            return spritesDaAnimacaoX2[];
            break;

        case 3:
            return spritesDaAnimacaoX3[];
            break;
}
```

Caso você use o mesmo Animator para mais de um personagem pode ser que todos fiquem com a mesma animação sincronizados, nesse caso terá que duplicar o Animator para cada personagem para que fiquem independentes

OBS: Eu criei os códigos pelo celular, então pode haver erros, (principalmente pq não sei se é possível um método que retorne uma matriz) mas o importante é entender a idéia e reproduzir você mesmo, espero ter ajudado.